# Using blender as image processor?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, lighting

Imported image as plane, added a simple frame, now I would like to lighten it so that the colors and values of the render exactly match the original. That is, apart from the frame, the image looks like the original. I can tweak the lighting setup until it looks right, but is there a simpler method?

Comment: did you try plugging the image/movie directly in the material output instead of using shader?

Comment: Transparency does't seem to work without shader. Any workaround available?

Comment: It's possible you could bring the image into the compositor and do the overlay there.

Comment: You can  plug the image/movie directly and still have transparency - just use a Mix Shader - Connect a Transparent BSDF to one of the inputs, and the (unshaded) image into the other - use image alpha as a mix factor, then connect the Mix Shader to the Material Output.

Comment: It's possible, but why? There are plenty of easier ways to edit images. Why would you want to do that in Blender? Could you also describe what kind processing you are after?

Comment: Christopher Bennet's solution works for me! As I am generating the frame in Blender, this goes a little further than just image processing, and as I need to do this for more than one image, using the compositor is cumbersome.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to use Blender as an image processor, but it's frankly not an efficient tool for it.

### Color management

[Color Management — Blender Manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/color_management.html)

By default, Blender uses the Filmic color management. Unless the picture you want to process was made using Blender with that color management and saved in a format that conserved it, you should change Blender's color management.

If you work on a random jpeg/png from the web, most likely you are dealing with a 8 bits per channel picture, which means you should use Blender's "*standard*" color management.

Head over the *Properties Editor* > *Render* tab >  *Color Management* panel > *View Transform* setting.

### Importing the picture

You can do this two ways:

- Use the addon *Import Images as Planes*, butt while browsing for an image: set up the importer to make a shadeless picture, and orient it to the camera:
  [image: addon setup]

  You will still need to fit it to the camera manually. But then, you can do anything you want to the color data going into your shader:

  [image: shader]

  Using shaders is IMHO more convoluted, but that's the only way if you need elements from the 3D scene, like 3D perspective, shades from the scene lights, volumetric effects and whatnot.
- Use the Compositor instead. It's made for color grading and picture manipulation. You have more color manipulation nodes, easy to access channel isolation, and a split viewer to compare results at a glance.

  [image: compositor]

In both cases, you will have to change the output resolution to your picture's resolution.

Comment: Anything that involves a shader is influences by lighting, which is exactly what I do not want here. So, this is not an answer.

Comment: My answer provides multiple solutions, not just shaders, and lights' influence on shaders depends on the shader itself, hence my answer mentions using the Shadeless setting of the *Import Images as Plane* addon which produces a "shadeless" shader that doesn't react to surroundings (including lights)  and doesn't transform the image's colors.